# Signed zone return unauthenticated answer

Tags: networking, security, dns

I used dig to validate my DNS server answers:

```
@dns1:/etc/bind$ dig a.com +dnssec +multi
```

This is what I get which does not conatins the (authenticated data) `ad` flag and does not contain a siganture:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> a.com +dnssec +multi
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29781
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;b.com.     IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
a.com.      300 IN A 104.17.193.53
a.com.      300 IN A 104.17.196.53
a.com.      300 IN A 104.17.195.53
a.com.      300 IN A 104.17.192.53
a.com.      300 IN A 104.17.194.53

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu May 24 10:26:39 BST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 118
```

My zone signed file is (after anonymizing the servers names):

```
; File written on Thu May 24 02:13:50 2018
; dnssec_signzone version 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu
com.            604800  IN SOA  dns1.com. admin.com. (
                    33         ; serial
                    604820     ; refresh (1 week 20 seconds)
                    86600      ; retry (1 day 3 minutes 20 seconds)
                    2419600    ; expire (4 weeks 6 minutes 40 seconds)
                    604600     ; minimum (6 days 23 hours 56 minutes 40 seconds)
                    )
            604800  RRSIG   SOA 7 1 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    Qfd9i1AndX/dmyQuksOo2CRXH5RyM7i52c3P
                    oXdLpfxsVFq+YTY4Hmcl6XLfvo5ES0G4uIOp
                    HFFpPfuGrcRBQVXmb6ANelbQc0bwCZxqUPkN
                    HyXi/nvQUDY2Yelc++BeTRW+2MilagE21Qu0
                    sBpF8/04gnt48LHJ/VYg3a9D7kmZr0vmBwLp
                    4ZBHkAjkPmmPVzoEUMsmUGHF8b8lzJ+jWvmZ
                    NIWMLHvpRUEVXZVfX1OGLTexIWenD+qYO5Th
                    NR6tyMRa9RkfLU3l189RVFyJ+yZFgj7Nqb0l
                    fdXGArpShUFdRyavVPaKPQhCHDsH4SZcN/kg
                    u/WZxsKy82c1CR+etg== )
            604800  NS  dns1.com.
            604800  RRSIG   NS 7 1 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    Qj1DMmEhfkU5KI9MVrIlgKmQ5DxTjGuRNJ8i
                    wmOkH0bkcNVbGPJRn8RDUFng1O3zlPr0F27t
                    CFfLhiZI8BQKKO8HKonybTcHSIoI+Ovlt0H8
                    NXp8w6HMWcMhDwMLUVTk2bcFP8uvB3v6QO4b
                    JfHk9j81nUrIrWw3yt+Rvgk2H6omiEAQ3brJ
                    Sb149CoK1bQNG1AnSOifoEBa39eqcpnIcZfo
                    wnzc6LMkr2VXQCVRAK6bhZEGneX8Dv+FzcZ0
                    d3Gk5xZktIoeQkjXqxSCYMDRP2po8Np8VsDT
                    21r28kv/iS2RKvcDOCqh8ymLe/OjbO8oyccg
                    e9cRd7KhlGEn7MXyRA== )
            604800  DNSKEY  256 3 7 (
                    AwEAAfZWrsuiFoAAGcOTDWyVlDoZjQC8CZc6
                    vmPDWucThvahdE5wArPSXaDbGKi6GoKF8Ex+
                    XCrzTs2hYXDp4XQALY6nvdz0TT+styyPP7UX
                    Xr8w7eOeGGpE0FVbT7A37uc3LKlae+lfo7us
                    mYCkLXnUFcPCfayuvkddYWtycOPc35lK/O/g
                    LMCnMssQHhERv2MdXEO2HW1X92N/IJZIW4Pu
                    6tJQYR/fnnrT/CBUnHEVMzFRbWnaFyOxxAj2
                    xIWKAHTsRL6m94wauXRtErvTpYhQ9oWQ2NyN
                    wcpkm74xAyn/zHzxTCenm8bz8B5l8/J6Z8EG
                    IIsUtTuH5kaWM9E2tuvd4+E=
                    ) ; ZSK; alg = NSEC3RSASHA1; key id = 12410
            604800  DNSKEY  257 3 7 (
                    AwEAAbc92MYUBPIs1L6lNAbubqRmZCfgv1h7
                    bPgIBMer16iAGtuDD5iKc12Lx1pgn8D6taNF
                    vBRYeYS9sNp0wsF5098bkbTc3T9HzDZGLU1b
                    gbYHpP9D9X4eyeB9Oo9q00P3USiXaFTWxp7J
                    OEq5PRPSZksD75SZA/JcWl24s4mC1fFCZ0jJ
                    pRE7dPxphNa5XCSl9V487GsC2eh6f6AqEcmT
                    kek6A6c102TsXG1ynoTO3UMxAUFDH0JkspGV
                    Pp/aTPzWxxXH2yN0sM6rAsns3FwmkmneqZez
                    XLuj9a6ovHbtPNy5umlx6RiFXda4e3walj6N
                    raeohzFgoKqrDBdo6HD/gAkxFs/hxrKLH8kY
                    twUvFsCLSAel9dmQ3hOX0N5uiRdWQivKss0b
                    dZyOHxT6V1srvCiJNUfvW3Lf60zKaOnEilSd
                    ak1yHP2HyAXVWTUW98SEWjxgiftQxZjSgMly
                    drL1Q/ywwlYX5D090BsavOeEPtjdg0JIQV9Q
                    EOVSJQO/EZDRrL+3WWfiO1/VohHoA2Msr0cV
                    N7HPfd1cMhXTZuGEeIevT33un3v6Mg2fHGbE
                    lpux1/cXR2hNw8YOX0bOBi9pNUTqYe7pGW15
                    TWTzM5MwoHX/U7qQYGtptmF9zf3BxeuvoLZI
                    SM2WTTvJqcluZAW8pwVqsnYBcRYRUopjGIn0
                    cn+L
                    ) ; KSK; alg = NSEC3RSASHA1; key id = 62649
            604800  RRSIG   DNSKEY 7 1 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    MuNVIE6oWV03+dXnXu+VufPQqfIgQvNIBODh
                    29Z67vH10RZkgFaFF/ElJB6Ue1L6pGTOQr75
                    9ooiNBZbP2aYMIfh4PPylJ1RB1KZmNxY1id/
                    QUZzQc3s2mHbnCqfWCND5dI98KgDht1RDgwu
                    ohwX8idwS+ENFWWdvk9hKe8+mlZlw9G7bNi6
                    XxqBkVNZR9G3EIaFCHb3ZqD6dppBMOUfGAHw
                    mEXkaPh0cpVjlz4z4Qs1BId7+ZDBRyn0hJG0
                    F2tuvw5NYRvggiPDYOA4juwKq/jxogV2+dCX
                    8JpC2bBaJiN481+hY9Hypy2R30wIanVaaOnY
                    i5iVkkU1ZdfAqe4urg== )
            604800  RRSIG   DNSKEY 7 1 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 62649 com.
                    HxKx8nsyZ/qtrAvhsFJ9r7EBBwhSCGh0FJfM
                    b7BqiqUcq164wnrDwFcRWWv84YMpndGVKKYy
                    +/P57a8tZIqnKQy4wsBA0DcHG2j49EGXuCOt
                    KABdUAop2t2qTToM4dWBxmnR7jOGUG9HPNd5
                    bkUvS6eg00vVPNJ+PEfQffgeUanmg+zQet9f
                    SNxK8Sd1IG/MVfKDecIvM947DHjlTQK2T5xS
                    qmqjC62WiaJzVUiy+eAlfOPaCfSdheV6XEB4
                    As6TLES8QwW09ShBrfnCTtPErRLupaVb9Gw4
                    J49S98srPqlh+RJi7h1DxgttcLkYwKlU3FI5
                    FqIXJqVFSlTdAVbHUubTiBJ/wLL1MtK37X+i
                    Be4pKYVpEaPA+SQWocgbpQP3TVuDK8fJNFNs
                    VrpUq48wOhWh2XfJ2BvOOzvUZ3rD2KXEGBbo
                    tHEdtOif1lwsCAeZuYv5HFdFewVYwmQb2NMw
                    McKpGfKfdOB4x1NTE+WT/BByYJmhffWyjxWJ
                    5fdTdCAwcos9G12qkfmb2xP5r0LO7ERU7s61
                    qr+AV5V2h9VcNkRQFE0oSVpMh1s1ZTgIdDjN
                    RGpsO5OAth3dYGsjmbZ3SewOzM+3+/Gj/ftX
                    Mqjxi7rOhlC17lF0xyLNpRAS4K7yDne+FOGe
                    geVZo8uIOu/2YJTRMWUFpH1B03VXM4jJ9us= )
            0   NSEC3PARAM 1 0 10 1C5A91FD094B6845
            0   RRSIG   NSEC3PARAM 7 1 0 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    qXpHn0q2GG/BK71mMYqCELsoHiFT6Oel82Jv
                    L/8HNAeGJamSc3Z7eUl8nAReQwCVNwE2+prf
                    2sbw/ylWzWiAgHII2Q/gQWr6UKcQjkIICrhk
                    F8Cl/D8CPtsZJFLYlOGno42ILmOfQIZ/QmTs
                    gZdF2vbNe0V2Ab93pAgC1sP5jIPFcL1VlteP
                    25GBY+IVPO8b165lMb9XCMDqZvx8DMXqn+xa
                    a/ofumNTD2klD9zBEECVcktNs//vun11A6RR
                    Thi323I2hXXl5zUBGmdprsvq7w8cZbvRdzy/
                    u9do1mWm/MbyI+xvBspH6UV5G9ZwHRU1qVVb
                    RIL34fRTv8T6rj5xYQ== )
dns1.com.       604800  IN A    192.168.56.3
            604800  RRSIG   A 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    aHB7ZCD8dDV4jMHJsUg23jjcm48tTnUvS8hy
                    UKy9fX6lZiqD4STEPubw3gUnTOKyr22HU3Xu
                    6bMOS9Wa919UUA5wogB24MvJSmyj9+myN+rq
                    GoBzyn/6BpdDQCOnvOVC52JzZh3k2bkT6fo/
                    RiWiEczQbNGvDKiQsls1XRBywu+n39S68crd
                    Ft9g2PCyHnbOpmnFPHhSGr/w0mC/ZxcejMqL
                    I8Melbp5dGpS62nobpBdIAyjAx1e7FT6AmFm
                    dOWtdSbaKViMG07IMfL8eepGbBAtfO0xgUt5
                    UTcdj2CVgLcQZ0jkIt6zCXXeNWkk8m2m2ILe
                    wYPPhwqjjYr/holMmg== )
a.com.      604800  IN A    192.168.56.7
            604800  RRSIG   A 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    0V7mUWUOuru41Rkp+RFp6eV13AHOdPnEanrV
                    msFGNbtaR893A2Lawvi9RWjKKxc/nqxKRdML
                    G+lL4SZS8rpWTovu615jLXO6EPFGLRg0Bs1L
                    Pq2T98uMLedga0kQycXhjQ4L9OBt5PjUzy2g
                    by6i2kd7WESqaSuwqZrHPhB9UO8bxGCrNH9/
                    OBSOpBNziT/0B+hezyKWw8zJjQtqPFll/2Td
                    5bRL3/aZJhof16QwevSTPU1EWHYCG5/6NtXS
                    JtIjZi1Pc8XayfiVdA+ZvmaLNRT2NyOMMfaD
                    MN4LAAUZXrvkId9QDoZuxzCazKKfgOotPGYt
                    8CHozVym7UyOpzpHtQ== )
            604800  TXT "some text"
            604800  RRSIG   TXT 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    Uta2/oGszVJAhm/DlGd7vnD+irg/GzyXlKHp
                    hYOVF4+IrWVO988QRLnRIz4dwvaDqWZKuCWy
                    LT86GnDWG+wXIkbzLgXO6Mq3+Wlu8u2aiu67
                    evTwqmaOYc8fBGcchioeHH7cs+1kbJrdccnC
                    Pf2U4A9uI6AiPv9Wg60wg+pObuuIcfWYRYe8
                    PFLXLWeq+pT7k/ePFoMDGH9m0/UnnAlIsOpg
                    /LHsh7hfAYDpIJSFRG5lRdZmoI90eqjWgmT3
                    pncNI4lnZXm9dWJqteauCdiBK8cmoTeQXno4
                    bZlyXVBBDTkmGR4i4H86lGCxArMjFdloyqQ0
                    2cDCCV8xjhKvvEegLQ== )
b.com.      604800  IN A    192.168.56.8
            604800  RRSIG   A 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    2ui9x3SjrrEvFkcPbfcfC/NQW0MQOv2jy/Bd
                    +0QBTL7uF7eNcDBQpY/FHKgL2YtAvPYIlkPk
                    PWFNjM8sTsJzOPofgT4D9SwUFWelUxTTasqm
                    6HLgv7HW0rRMMM/OG6XUQsaUSZxbcFW6TxKT
                    PyvjxjzHUv9HP22iswXQXGd5OGGh1o45HjUP
                    mUMkmpWCAaqg3o+VghZ9HJdwGlxl60LsXtZ9
                    Oc23OnM+7vFuCYeo3TscjXt38Dlj10Y5zwdJ
                    g+MOiGlg64NOsC+kHGTEVeVc5kEWzKRLfOLl
                    tBRoFHxjQH3RQGiRzEXH8dGhqY0ygAefOEtl
                    9AH0vm3Tqp6uaP2Omg== )
            604800  TXT ""
            604800  RRSIG   TXT 7 2 604800 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    etX8lM00XXK9hUMM4FVsc51zuYOCz2+6qNLM
                    3LTl54DGObE2kOtNDPtVKSBd9oP2ppNK7MxT
                    f82wyS5l19B7CjGg6Z/ywcok8ztcCYcGVpeF
                    b8aqugazU4+82jC/x+XBv2f+vYwj44kWCQQ+
                    hXoCNssaW71Y4IFQSgiC3GI//v+kMAZZhHDO
                    Ur6MEboWRIpNghpQcMuxVP+9bRfj/gDaIahu
                    /y52AnW68P8+LaX8wEoWv6Eg0HK5k5Sp++LA
                    0L0WYF0HizAkhbJtitAYzyQpyeHsji1DpYve
                    KTHGCFLl6reM//wZZUvv8r1vpq3SsZMg/7Hp
                    nO5+XlWyAB77vYmimA== )
8NRLOA7UP8TGKLFJ7A6KPTIS503NJ4NB.com. 604600 IN NSEC3 1 1 10 1C5A91FD094B6845 (
                    QNU3FGJ5VOCSBIP3N93ITKLM4OP6GMCO
                    A TXT RRSIG )
            604600  RRSIG   NSEC3 7 2 604600 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    0qFfv4wr6WYSb4JlrtOlmPWykmCUKNdADlH8
                    Ok4eS2JXftWpweGKKUa5hHoVR/09ssEMiu4X
                    hIhTAKEDWHfdrvOMb1NPH6n+m/tVr/dh593T
                    IAO6VuhNKDo0XGdH5wEg+lEQPNkhjr+I7qjL
                    IeSjMN3LNy9D+ouZdW3NBbyBPVYqK86X2V71
                    5lpWAPqQUV/DUljCs567aoNd4zFzImPi2RcW
                    iZO+iQVwGIfyxMvzd+D3+VZrwpr6GNdUKUHn
                    Vn95mBAIMlDA/cx8pb+2+qMc9HbGgumlweZw
                    e5lAe44WfVzvAvtZaQWEfqJ0qOCGbRCyAn3m
                    0l1Jye4nouPQYm9q9A== )
QNU3FGJ5VOCSBIP3N93ITKLM4OP6GMCO.com. 604600 IN NSEC3 1 1 10 1C5A91FD094B6845 (
                    TVQJ9TFT4DPK7IGFE32TKLFG6EH2CUH5
                    A RRSIG )
            604600  RRSIG   NSEC3 7 2 604600 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    qZCi11tgJWJwjK2NI9KTVkcaJ0Eln0NVDsjM
                    SQzZwIUx4p1wBbDNbMfntzY3tbFV9g7y4d37
                    gN02o/4O0JKNDHh8qA03zMTGc4129sUBD3We
                    m2eA4X4FSSv1ChTP75C3kxA07a/7DvkG3i3m
                    TQ2pOJ6T0c/z1c8TAjuW/4DTz8ZKYKUlvMH6
                    BvlGIwXPjk0wwQE6l2naBQTJoyKkAfGc4yM0
                    hOjweOo5xrxdd7xmppSBaTpIVgzIzLBy/lAP
                    3PPVQ3vaUHH6boFzQtLP4/io/3FG3KCAAmN0
                    r9iZn9SWPProRlInMyvOp1xBdHDvrWsPsBTu
                    LyX+5GVBHvpijahmuA== )
TVQJ9TFT4DPK7IGFE32TKLFG6EH2CUH5.com. 604600 IN NSEC3 1 1 10 1C5A91FD094B6845 (
                    0J67JF0QNUUEKT5VF6FQPCRR9T8I8RT7
                    NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM )
            604600  RRSIG   NSEC3 7 2 604600 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    gud9iAHIRi4vR6eCgwOe6Xz0fR5F1qksJz6x
                    7Zu0jj6BCMmvC1rT2AiW2GNiCiD006f5kN6d
                    omVpac955Ze/KBoMHg6YiOJXVK9OTo86vBxd
                    a6QJKLngoI/hgrsoRen8V+jaA3QvBxNkWJAH
                    TJrcyKQj7QVXUcenz7U3HPWCifq5TTlC6+0B
                    Vw4oM0tE2Umt4qzkEObW4dPd5HY4/SGk2LYa
                    f8tu4ipUZu5IwG6r05vdnnpa5plc7JlRELD3
                    du+vDLphwDQ3/E/r1rJCcwJcxnNjol6Zx/ej
                    s0cpqtarusF0sMlCKzCy5vEzaj+YuipAx0sy
                    rnDMeQLku1nE9lNyIQ== )
0J67JF0QNUUEKT5VF6FQPCRR9T8I8RT7.com. 604600 IN NSEC3 1 1 10 1C5A91FD094B6845 (
                    8NRLOA7UP8TGKLFJ7A6KPTIS503NJ4NB
                    A TXT RRSIG )
            604600  RRSIG   NSEC3 7 2 604600 (
                    20180623001350 20180524001350 12410 com.
                    8ZowNBjQXgaAx89kjTmgCu/9lYLk14L+xTWr
                    LeqTR03x44M3yuU5sjy61YHr/fc51D57+Rob
                    WjWcf4fLg4PEXg3jdj4f155e7I0Fh4O2hdmS
                    wvD4TuKDtcxKX0lq6oSPi3VNXMzEijFI7jFD
                    yHHj+ATPDPMIaQAnVp40aYd1L+0SSPJyAm/u
                    eG8Y2WKdFPCZ30VBZ4M/nOKD0QtEckbLW8dm
                    RHSoRfc1V7KFTeIRcjh6YHPy6QkeJzVt8DaA
                    0JKi9AD+ZtVRUYwq2W8vWcuTn0QCxmM0W8Z+
                    OBW1ennfzNTP9J9SSnai8DNcO0uzI/0kV4a8
                    H18OCk+4wjlE8NPSCQ== )
```

Comment: Why are you anonymizing them? And what software is running at 127.0.1.1 (the DNS resolver)?

Comment: I prefer this for privacy. Are they necessary for the answer? this is a private experimental setup anyways. The SW is BIND 9.10.

Comment: Is it the same BIND that's authoritative for the zone? I don't really have a good guess as to why it won't give you DNSSEC records _at all_, otherwise I'd post an answer... however, the authoritative server will never give you the `AD` flag.

Comment: Yes. I only have one BIND DNS server which is the one responsible for resolving the names for a.com and b.com directly from the client (this is my understanding of authoritative). The resolving itself works fine and I tried to access the `a.com` and `b.com` from my own device browser. But DNSSEC does not seem correct.